# Как удалить атрибут data-disable-with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Помогите пожалуйста избавиться от следующего явления.

В rails5 я использую форму. Кнопка отправки создаётся при помощи хэлпера:
`<%= f.submit class: 'submit_btn float_r', value: 'Отправить`' %>

в результате firebug показывает следующее:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Отправить" class="submit_btn float_r" data-disable-with="Создать Contact message">
```

Как видите, появился атрибут data-disable-with. Проблема в том, что после клика по этой кнопке на короткое время(1 сек.) надпись на кнопке заменяется с "Отправить" на "Создать Contact message"

Хотелось бы избежать этого глюка.

Код формы:

```
<div class="contact_form" id="contact_form">
  <%= form_for(contact_message) do |f| %>
    <% if contact_message.errors.any? %>
      <div class="error_explanation" id="error_explanation">
        <div class="head_errors">Форма содержит следующие ошибки:</div>

        <ul>
          <% contact_message.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field float_l">
      <%= f.label :name, 'Имя' %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'required input_field' %>
    </div>

    <div class="field float_r">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'validate-email required input_field' %>
    </div>

    <div class="cleaner h20"></div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :message, 'Сообщение' %>
      <%= f.text_area :message, class: 'required' %>
    </div>

    <div class="cleaner h20"></div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit class: 'submit_btn float_r', value: 'Отправить' %>
    </div> 
  <% end %> 
</div>
```

Результат в firebug:

```
<div class="contact_form" id="contact_form">
  <form class="new_contact_message" id="new_contact_message" action="/contact_messages" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="NISCCQTwxfeIUUYXkpd6rAMdGwwW6m+B4eOhx5h++C/Hum9VCCe5l2DX+yg1IMXNZRx3Jvj2nFTzR5Xzi+AvbQ==">

    <div class="field float_l">
      <label for="contact_message_name">Имя</label>
      <input class="required input_field" type="text" name="contact_message[name]" id="contact_message_name">
    </div>

    <div class="field float_r">
      <label for="contact_message_email">Email</label>
      <input class="validate-email required input_field" type="text" name="contact_message[email]" id="contact_message_email">
    </div>

    <div class="cleaner h20"></div>

    <div class="field">
      <label for="contact_message_message">Сообщение</label>
      <textarea class="required" name="contact_message[message]" id="contact_message_message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="cleaner h20"></div>

    <div class="actions">
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Отправить" class="submit_btn float_r" data-disable-with="Создать Contact message">
    </div> 
</form></div>
```

Comment: Это какая версия Rails? В 4.2.5 я такого не наблюдаю. В документации к Rails 5 и вовсе сказано: "Defaults to value attribute.", т. е., должен совпадать.

Comment: Это в rails 5.0.0

Comment: kalinin@kalinin ~/rails/test5 $ rails -v

Rails 5.0.0.1

Comment: @cyklop77 Что не воспроизводится под Rails 5, вы точно сами data-disable-with нигде не вставляете, например, через JS?

Comment: @cheops ну, этим занимается `jquery-ujs`... Возможно, разгадка в вызове `form_for`? Какой-нибудь `remote` или что-то такого калибра...

Comment: Дополнил вопрос полным кодом формы. Там всё стандарно и минималистично.

Answer (score -1):

Нужно просто указать:

```
<%= f.submit class: 'submit_btn float_r', data: { disable_with: false }, value: 'Отправить' %>
```